# What is *so* wrong with case class inheritance?

Tags: scala, inheritance, case-class

While looking for something else, quite out of mere coincidence I stumbled upon few comments about how diabolical case class inheritance is. There was this thing called `ProductN` , wretches and kings, elves and wizards and how some kind of a very desirable property is lost with case classes inheritance. So what is so wrong with case class inheritance ?

Answer (score 120):

One word: **equality**

`case` classes come with a supplied implementation of `equals` and `hashCode`. The equivalence relation, known as `equals` works like this (i.e. must have the following properties):

1. For all `x`; `x equals x` is `true` (reflexive)
2. For `x`, `y`, `z`; if `x equals y` and `y equals z` then `x equals z` (transitive)
3. For `x`, `y`; if `x equals y` then `y equals x` (symmetric)

As soon as you allow for equality within an inheritance hierarchy you can break 2 and 3. this is trivially demonstrated by the following example:

```
case class Point(x: Int, y: Int)
case class ColoredPoint(x: Int, y: Int, c: Color) extends Point(x, y)
```

Then we have:

```
Point(0, 0) equals ColoredPoint(0, 0, RED)
```

But *not*

```
ColoredPoint(0, 0, RED) equals Point(0, 0)
```

You might argue that all class hierarchies may have this problem, and this is true. But case classes exist specifically to simplify equality from a developer's perspective (among other reasons), so having them behave *non-intuitively* would be the definition of an own goal!

---

There were other reasons as well; notably the fact that [`copy` did not work as expected](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/3289) and [interaction with the pattern matcher](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/1582).

Comment: And what about a little elaboration :) ?

Comment: It seems like such an asymmetric equivalence would be a useful thing in the OO paradigm, in the same way that at the type level a `ColoredPoint` is-a `Point` but not vice-versa. Might have to call it something other than `equals` though... maybe `subEquals`?

Comment: @LuigiPlinge perhaps `canReplace`, `supersedes`, `specifies`, or `overrides` for the reverse relationship? Anything to indicate the `>=`-ness (or `>:` if you like) of it. It seems much easier for me to name it in terms of `>=` rather than `<=`.

Comment: On second thoughts, such a thing would be tricky (impossible?) to implement due to the possibility of upcasting, so maybe it's not such a great idea

Comment: This example is not compilable in 2.10.2

Comment: a generic equals is trivially easy to implement that would satisfy equality, make the class a member of the comparison. the copy thing looks like its just a bug, and interaction with the pattern matcher should work, as it does for non case class hierarchies.

Comment: Exactly, ColoredPoint.class != Point.class?

Comment: `case class` only gets `equals` when none of its parents override it, so in this case `ColoredPoint` would use `Point`'s `equals`/`hashCode` (I don't know if this was already the case in 2012) which is symmetric (and reflective and transitive). You could argue `ColoredPoint(0, 0, RED) == ColoredPoint(0, 0, GREEN)` is unintuitive, and I'd agree, but the problem is not with case class inheritance: you have exactly the same problem if `Point` is a non-`case` class overriding `equals`. `copy` is more of a problem.

Comment: Would anybody extend this answer by providing the best practice solution to the ColoredPoint problem, please?

Answer (score -2):

That is not overall true. And this is worse than lie.

As mentioned by [aepurniet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/159326/aepurniet) in any case class successor which constricts a definition area must redefine the equality because pattern matching must work exactly as equality (if try to match `Point` as `ColoredPoint` then it will not matched since `color` is not exists).

That give understanding to how the equality of case class hierarchy could be implemented.

```
case class Point(x: Int, y: Int)
case class ColoredPoint(x: Int, y: Int, c: Color) extends Point(x, y)

Point(0, 0) equals ColoredPoint(0, 0, RED)  // false
Point(0, 0) equals ColoredPoint(0, 0, null) // true

ColoredPoint(0, 0, RED) equals Point(0, 0)  // false
ColoredPoint(0, 0, null) equals Point(0, 0) // true
```

Eventually it is possible to satisfy requirements of the equality relation even for case class successor (without overriding of equality).

```
case class ColoredPoint(x: Int, y: Int, c: String)
class RedPoint(x: Int, y: Int) extends ColoredPoint(x, y, "red")
class GreenPoint(x: Int, y: Int) extends ColoredPoint(x, y, "green")

val colored = ColoredPoint(0, 0, "red")
val red1 = new RedPoint(0, 0)
val red2 = new RedPoint(0, 0)
val green = new GreenPoint(0, 0)

red1 equals colored // true
red2 equals colored // true
red1 equals red2 // true

colored equals green // false
red1 equals green // false
red2 equals green // false

def foo(p: GreenPoint) = ???
```