# Does scala have shortcuts for functional objects?

Tags: oop, scala, functional-programming, ocaml

I'm writing class in Scala and want to write some update methods that will return a modified version of the original object. I want the class to continue to be immutable of course.

Of course I could do it by explicitly creating a new object of the appropriate type each time, as is done in [this example](http://blog.knoldus.com/2012/08/25/functional-object-2/), however that breaks in the face of inheritance since calling the methods on an instance of the subclass would instead return an instance of the superclass.

FWIW, I come from the land of OCaml which has special syntax to support functional objects. For an example, see [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.00/manual005.html#toc30)

So, does Scala have an equivalent for `{< x = y >}` in OCaml?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the concept of "functional objects" in ocaml, but I think case classes may have what you need.  For a simple use case, they provide some nice syntax and convenient functions like `copy`:

```
scala> case class Foo(a: Int, b: Int)
defined class Foo

scala> val f = Foo(1, 2)
f: Foo = Foo(1,2)

scala> val g = f.copy(a = 2)
g: Foo = Foo(2,2)
```

However it does come with some important limitations (like lack of inheritance).  See this page for more info:  http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/107 and this thread for why it's a bad idea to inherit from case classes: [What is *so* wrong with case class inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11158929/what-is-so-wrong-with-case-class-inheritance)

Comment: It kind of feels like it's conflating two things but I guess it's the closest there is in Scala.