# Why case-to-case inheritance is prohibited in Scala

Tags: scala

The following code will yield a compile error saying "case-to-case inheritance is prohibited".

```
case class BaseEvent(eventType: String, payload: Map[String, Any] = Map())
case class ChildEvent(payload: Map[String, Any] = Map()) extends BaseEvent("ChildEventType", payload)
```

I understand I can change BaseEvent to a normal class or a trait to get it compile. But I'd still like to understand why Scala doesn't allow case-to-case inheritance.

Comment: Probably issues with matching when you have a childEvent object it would be both a BaseEvent and a ChildEvent. This is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: Actually it was there, but got deprecated. Please see some discussion here  hinting at the problems it had http://scala-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/scala-Do-you-use-case-class-inheritance-td2001640.html

Comment: Also this previous SO answer seems to point to the issues http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11158929/what-is-so-wrong-with-case-class-inheritance