# If case class inheritance is prohibited, how to represent this?

Tags: scala, algebraic-data-types

I am trying to create the case classes as explained in [this article](https://gleichmann.wordpress.com/2011/03/06/functional-scala-a-little-expression-language-with-algebraic-datatypes-and-pattern-matching/)

```
sealed abstract case class Exp()
case class Literal(x:Int) extends Exp
case class Add(a:Exp, b:Exp) extends Exp
case class Sub(a:Exp,b:Exp) extends Exp
```

However, I am getting the following error in IntelliJ. I understand why it is prohibited ([Why case-to-case inheritance is prohibited in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30454354/why-case-to-case-inheritance-is-prohibited-in-scala)). What is the alternate way here?

```
Error:(2, 13) case class Literal has case ancestor A$A34.A$A34.Exp, but case-to-case inheritance is prohibited. To overcome this limitation, use extractors to pattern match on non-leaf nodes.
case class Literal(x:Int) extends Exp
           ^
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`Exp` shouldn't use the `case` keyword. That is, a `sealed abstract case class` will rarely, if ever, make sense to use.

In this specific case, the only extra thing you get from `sealed abstract case class Exp()` is an auto-generated companion object `Exp` that has an `unapply` method. And this `unapply` method won't be very useful, because there isn't anything to extract from the generic `Exp`. That is, you only care about decomposing `Add`, `Sub`, etc.

This is just fine:

```
sealed abstract class Exp

case class Literal(x: Int) extends Exp

case class Add(a: Exp, b: Exp) extends Exp

case class Sub(a: Exp, b: Exp) extends Exp
```